How can I add background box to words in ASS subtitle format?
I want to add a background box to the word being spoken, I have tried different ASS subtitle tags but none seems to output my requirement. Which tags can be used to achieve that?
I was trying different combination of tags found here.
For example, this adds an outline but not an opaque box:
Dialogue: 0,0:00:02.50,0:00:20.00,,,0,0,0,,{\bord3\3c&H404040&\c&HFFFFFF&}الفلوس


My target is to look like the below:


Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870169/how-to-set-background-to-subtitle-in-ffmpeg

@RicardoBohner, it seems the link shows how to add a background across the whole line, my case is to put it per word (similar like attached screenshot)

Ah ok, than look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63583741/highlight-some-words-in-text-with-ffmpeg-drawtext

@RicardoBohner Do you know any way to maker the borders rounded? I'm looking something like border radius.

@Armen Sanoyan No sorry, no much of an expert in ffmpeg eighter...
